# Logic in setter and state pattern

Tags: oop, design-patterns, state-pattern

Let's define a simple state machine:

```
public enum State {

    A, B, C, D;

    private List<State> validChange;

    static {
        A.validChange = Arrays.asList(B);
        B.validChange = Arrays.asList(C);
        C.validChange = Arrays.asList(A, D);
        D.validChange = Arrays.asList(D);
    }

    public boolean couldChange(State newState) {
        return validChange.contains(newState);
    }
}
```

and a simple state object

```
public class StateObject {

    private State currentState;

    public State getCurrentState() {
        return currentState;
    }

    public void setCurrentState(State currentState) {
        if (this.currentState != null && !this.currentState.couldChange(currentState)) {
            throw new IllegalStateException(String.format("Can not change from %s to %s", this.currentState, currentState));
        }
        this.currentState = currentState;
    }
}
```

As we see in the setter we check that the state change is valid. My questions:

1. is it a good solution to add some logic to setter method (we are not interest how does it work but only fact logic inside setter)?
2. when should we add logic, when should we not?
3. if not why?

Comment: Koziołek, you might be better off posting this kind of questions at the [Code Review SE](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 2):

The state pattern has its reference implementation for years. The implementation is free of your concerns. States are not represented as enums but rather as classes inheriting from the same base class. This way the implementation of transition between states is much simpler and cleaner as each state is only responsible for its own transitions.

I wonder why you decide to try your own approach instead of following a good, reliable practice.

Answering your question - there is nothing fundamentally wrong in having a code in a setter. But the way you approach the implementation of the state pattern raises unnecessary issues.

Comment: the reason why I use enums is simple - we have web service that use state object, but state is represented by strings. Mapping this to enums is much more easier than mapping to classes.

Comment: With a simple factory class, mapping strings to classes could be as easy as mapping strings to enum values. And benefits from following a reference implementation should be noticeable.

Answer (score 0):

1. In general, yes, it's OK to have logic in setters.
2. If you think [SRP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle) is a good idea, then **you're OK if you add logic that is related to setter functionality**, which primarily means maintaining the integrity of the object w.r.t to the change of the attribute's value.
3. Like I said, one of the cases when this is a bad idea is an SRP violation.

In fact, I would say the code posted shows an example of such a violation, since the setter has two responsibilities:

- initialize the `State` of a new `StateObject` instance,
- process any transition into a new `State`.

The second responsibility would become even more apparent if you'd implement the remaining part of a canonical state machine, i.e. the full transition function, including transition actions.

A primary example of where this separation of concerns would become important is in code where you only have setter injection - how do you differentiate between initialization and transition in this case? With this code, you can't.

---

Additionally, I believe the case would become more apparent if you'd refactor `validChange` to `StateObject`, which I think is necessary, since the current code breaks encapsulation - `State`, a **state machine label**, contains "guard specification" for the state transition function. Let's say you would like to have the same labels in a different state machine - as the code currently stands, you can't have that (*there's even a nice code smell that should point you towards the problem, as instead of using an `enum` constructor, you're forced to create a static initialization block*).